# Send post data from android

Tags: java, android, rest

I'm sending a POST request to certain server.

I can send the date from curl like this:

```
     curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST https://ictexpo.herokuapp.com/users -d "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"Choity\"}}"
```

But when I want to send the same data from java I don't get the outcome.

```
        String urlParameters = "{\"user\" : {\"name\" :  \"lssl\" }}";

        URL url2 = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url2.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);



        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        //Get Response

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
```

Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting exceptopn?

Comment: I hope it's not NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: Logcat data is here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15047984/logcat_data.txt

Comment: where are you sending this request, in main thread or using asynctask?

Comment: Thanks all, it's solved, I was doing network operation in main thread.